# remove the Review step in Onepage checkout in magento

Tags: onepage-checkout

I want to remove Review step in Onepage checkout. I used url
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/checkout/customizing_onepage_checkout_-_remove_shipping_method?do=show

but not clear how to use to remove review step from checkout

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the review step by overriding the savePaymentAction() in Mage_Checkout_OnepageController.

NP : You can use getCheckoutRedirectUrl() in the payment method class, to be redirected after the payment step.

Hope that can help.